# I am making an User(AbsrtactUser) model and I need to make a field that auto increments

Tags: django, django-models

```
    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        email =  models.EmailField(unique=True,blank=True,max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')
        phone_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="phone number")
        ids = models.UUIDField(blank=True,null=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        #parent_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
        role_id = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

How do i create role_id as auto_increment field.
I tried making role_id field AutoField but that just gave me an error that we cannot have 2 Autofield in one model and I dont want to make any changes with django default id primary key as i need that field.
can we give reference of **(id primary key)** to **(role id)**..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method to provide a default value to the field.

```
 def auto_increment():
        last = CustomUser.objects.all().last()
        if not last:
            return 1
        return last.role_id + 1
    
    
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        email =  models.EmailField(unique=True,blank=True,max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')
        phone_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="phone number")
        ids = models.UUIDField(blank=True,null=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        role_id = models.IntegerField(default=auto_increment)
```

Another way is to override the save method of the model and do the calculation before saving the new object.

Comment: Thanks @Ajay Saini its working perfectly only did a change instead of returning last.role_id i returned last.id: Thanks a lot